# Mysql server rebooted due to select query

Tags: mysql

we are using Mysql 5.1 and executed below query ,the server got rebooted ,we have enough memory space also.
 select GROUP_CONCAT(bp.xyz_product_id order by bp.xyz_product_id desc ) from blc_product bp where product_category='master' limit 5 offset 0

when i went to error log ifound below error message.

```
Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (2b9364005500): select GROUP_CONCAT(bp.xyz_product_id order by bp.xyz_product_id desc ) from blc_product bp where product_category='master' limit 5 offset 0
Connection ID (thread ID): 1027283
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
140507 06:20:20 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
140507 06:20:20 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
140507  6:20:20 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024 (request: 8106)
140507  6:20:20 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140507  6:20:20 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140507  6:20:20 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140507  6:20:20 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140507  6:20:20 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140507  6:20:20 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 24.0G
140507  6:20:22 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140507  6:20:22 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140507  6:20:22  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
```